# Laravel 5: Password change only when password input is changed

Tags: php, laravel-5, updatemodel

I am currently working on a user edit form on my Laravel app and it includes a password input. Currently each time I click on the update button it updates the password even without changing the current password. I would like have the password reset happen only when there is an input. Below is my code:

User Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   //
    $user = User::findOrFail($id); 
    $user->name = $request->get('name'); 
    $user->email = $request->get('email'); 
    $user->password = $request->get('password');

    $this->validate($request, User::validationRules());

    $user->save(); 
    return redirect('/user');     
}
```

User.php (Model)

```
public static function validationRules( $attributes = null )
{
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:100',
        'email' => 'required|email' 
    ];

    // no list is provided
    if(!$attributes)
        return $rules;

    // a single attribute is provided
    if(!is_array($attributes))
        return [ $attributes => $rules[$attributes] ];

    // a list of attributes is provided
    $newRules = [];
    foreach ( $attributes as $attr )
        $newRules[$attr] = $rules[$attr];
    return $newRules;
}

public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{  
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
}
```

Comment: This is probably the case because the password is saved in the browser's password manager and the browser autofills the field. You should probably either make a confirmation field (to make sure that the user confirms that he wants the password to change to that password) or make a hidden password field before the real password field, so that the browser doesn't autofill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cracked my own problem. There is no problem in the model, I focused more on the controller. I created new variables based on the request so the newpassword and verifypassword fields would be clear. They are both matched and if it is correct, it will give a new input. In the model, the password is encrypted so no need to use bcrypt within the controller.

I hope this helps others facing a similar problem and would like to have update the password with a verification input within the same form.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // 
    $data = $request->all(); 

    $userinput['name'] = $data['name']; 
    $userinput['email'] = $data['email']; 

    //check to see if field new password is filled. 
    if($data['newpassword']) 
    { 
      //verify that the newpassword input matches the verify password
      if($data['newpassword'] == $data['verifypassword']) {  
         $userinput['password'] = $data['newpassword']; 
      } 

      //else statement can be made for the case if newpassword != verifypassword

    }

    $this->validate($request, User::validationRules());

    User::find($id)->update($userinput);  
    return redirect('/user');     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try that

```
$data = $request->all();
if( empty( $data['password'] ) ){
    unset($data['password']);
}
User::find($id)->update($data);
```

I usually deal with this.Good luck.

Comment: Just tried this out and it doesn't work. But I do now get the concept of it. :)